# How to Screen Cast on several computers from one computer?

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, screencast

So my question is that i have dozen of computers in my class and i want to share my screen to others computers so that students can see my screen on their screen and they can't do anything with their computer ,they can just watch the screen and see my computer on their screen , the clear question is how can i connect them to each other to use this way for screen casting ?

**Note** : the computers are in same network Ethernet and they don't have wifi connection

Comment: I am not sure. Have you tried Team Viewer ?

Comment: Can you not use a projector?

Comment: Yes i can but its a big class and i want all the students watch it and learn it correctly konrad